# TYPO3 v10: Install extension with cmd on Windows 10

Tags: cmd, xampp, composer-php, typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm trying to install a typo3(v10) extension with composer under XAMPP in the `C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\public\typo3` folder. I'm on Windows 10, I use `cmd` in admin to install with composer.

With cmd, I accessed my TYPO3 folder using the following command: `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3` then I started composer. I typed the command:

`composer require typo3/cms-introduction`

I get a message that told me the extension is installed. Following the instructions, I must now enter the following commands:

`./vendor/bin/typo3 extension: activate bootstrap_package`

`./vendor/bin/typo3 extension: activate introduction`

But cmd returns me the following message (an english translation from the message i get in french)

> '.' is not recognized as an internal order or external, an executable
> program or a batch file.

How can I activate those 2 extensions?

Comment: Have you tried using `extension:activate`, as given in the documentation (without a space)?

Answer (score 0):

(De-)Activating TYPO3 extensions is always possible via the extension manager module in the TYPO3 backend.

Side note:
Maybe you want to check out [DDEV-local](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) as local development environment instead of XAMPP. DDEV uses Docker and is an awesome powerful tool but easy to use. And it provides a native shell for commands like yours above.
A big plus is the very helpful community. If you have problems, register an account at [my.typo3.org](https://my.typo3.org/), request your [TYPO3 Slack invitation](https://my.typo3.org/about-mytypo3org/slack) and go to the [#ddev Slack channel](https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C8TRNQ601).

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the answer. I already try to install a DDEV Typo3 on local with Ubuntu, but my knoledge was more than basic, it took me around 10 hours to install it following a youtube video of 39 minutes. At the end i got a partially cms install, everithing seem ok untill i look at maintenance, setting and upgrade, they were all blank. I fynally install one following video and instruction with composer and Xampp, when i restart my local server this morning the extensions was all there just have to click on the activate button and it did it. Thanl again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows:

`vendor\bin\typo3 extension:activate <EXTKEY>`

*Note:* You have to solve dependencies manually, but you will be warned and the extension will not be activated if dependencies are absent.